# Add a cube and link it with python

Tags: python

I'm a bit puzzled, I can add a simple light with the code:

```
light_data = bpy.data.lights.new('light', type='POINT')
light = bpy.data.objects.new('light', light_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light)
```

However, I can't create a simple cube. I didn't manege to find documentation so I'm not sure what's correct:

```
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Basic_Cube')
basic_cube = bpy.data.objects.new("Basic_Cube", mesh)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(basic_cube)
```

This creates no simple cube:
[image]

I would love your input on this

Comment: use `bmesh` module https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_cube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import bpy
import bmesh


bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=1)

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Basic_Cube')
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
mesh.update()
bm.free()

basic_cube = bpy.data.objects.new("Basic_Cube", mesh)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(basic_cube)
```

Comment: This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips and code only posts rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Let @nammerkage decide whether the answer is helpful or not.